# How to create fusion chart with angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, fusioncharts

I created an angular 4 project for CRUD operation of users. Now I need to to create a chart (fusion chart). So I follow below link

https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/using-with-javascript-libraries/angular4/creating-charts-using-the-fusioncharts-angular4-component.html

But some error is coming,
[image]

I installed fusion chart plugin using

```
npm install fusioncharts angular4-fusioncharts --save
```

Then in app.module.ts I add

```
 import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
 import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
 import * as FintTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint';
 import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular4-fusioncharts';

 FusionChartsModule.forRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FintTheme) // in imports
```

And in my userlist.ts file I add

```
export class UserListComponent implements OnInit {

  private users:User[];
  height = 400;
  type = 'column2d';
  dataFormat = 'json';
  dataSource;

  constructor(private router:Router,
             private userService:UserService) {
   this.dataSource = {
   "chart": {
    "caption": "Harry's SuperMart",
    "subCaption": "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
    "numberprefix": "$",
    "theme": "fint"
   },
   "data": [{
    "label": "Bakersfield Central",
    "value": "880000"
   },
    {
      "label": "Garden Groove harbour",
      "value": "730000"
    },
    {
      "label": "Los Angeles Topanga",
      "value": "590000"
    },
    {
      "label": "Compton-Rancho Dom",
      "value": "520000"
    },
    {
      "label": "Daly City Serramonte",
      "value": "330000"
    }
  ]
}
```

}
   }

And in userlist.component.html

```
  <fusioncharts
        height="350"
        type="Column2D"
        dataFormat="JSON"
        [dataSource]="dataSource">
  </fusioncharts>
```

Please help me to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

```
Hi Subho Please Look it .... 

- Package.json:  Install these libraries :
 1. npm install angular4-fusioncharts@1.0.0
 2. npm install fusioncharts@3.12.2

-index.html : add libraries : 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js?cacheBust=56"></script>

-add.module.ts :

//library imports for fusion charts
import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
import { FusionChartsModule ,FusionChartsCoreService } from 'angular4-fusioncharts';
import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
import * as FintTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint';
FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts,Charts,FintTheme)

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FusionChartsModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ] 
})
export class AppModule{ }

===================================
- app.component.html
<fusioncharts [id]="id" [width]="width" [height]="height" [type]="'column2d'" [dataFormat]="dataFormat" [dataSource]="dataSource"></fusioncharts>

==============================================
-app.component.ts

export class FusionChartsComp {
  id = 'chart1';
  width = 600;
  height = 400;
  type = 'angulargauge';
  dataFormat = 'json';
  dataSource;

 constructor() {
this.dataSource = {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Harry's SuperMart-Test",
        "subCaption": "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue-Desc",
        "numberprefix": "$",
        "exportEnabled": "1",
        "exportMode": "client",
       // "theme": "carbon"

        // "caption": "U.S. Federal Employment Report 2014",
        // "subcaption": "Full-time employee's age distribution",
        // "xaxisname": "Age group",
        // "yaxisname": "Number of employees",
        "palette": "2",
        "rotatevalues": "1",
        "valuefontcolor": "043c62",
        "valuefontbold": "1",
        "placevaluesinside": "1",
        "animation": "1",
        // "plotspacepercent": "0",
        // "palettecolors": "#b2d9f9,#f7c018,#94bf13,#ff9049,#069191,#d74a4a,#914b91,#5c882b,#0c93d8",
        // "plottooltext": "$value Employees under $label (age group)",
        "theme": "zune"





      },
      "data": [
        {
          "label": "Bakersfield Central",
          "value": "880000"
        },
        {
          "label": "Garden Groove harbour",
          "value": "730000"
        },
        {
          "label": "Los Angeles Topanga",
          "value": "590000"
        },
        {
          "label": "Compton-Rancho Dom",
          "value": "520000"
        },
        {
          "label": "Daly City Serramonte",
          "value": "330000"
        }


      ]
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you for this. This was a life saver. The current examples (as of 4/12/18) do not work on the Fusion Charts website and Ionic 4. This got me headed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You didn´t imported something correctly.

Maybe add the imports also in your userlist.ts file

Answer (score 0):

you need install both:

`npm install angular4-fusioncharts --save`

and

`npm install fusioncharts --save`

according to their `npm` page here[enter link description here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular4-fusioncharts)

And also checkout my app.module, cause I feel like it's different than yours:

[image]

However, it's still useless, 'cause it can visualize only hardcoded data as far as it only can draw it from constructor visualization.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import FusionChartsModule in the @NgModule. Also, don't use `FusionChartsModule.forRoot`, use `FusionChartsModule.fcRoot` instead.

```
    import { FusionChartsModule } from 'angular4-fusioncharts';
    import * as FusionCharts from 'fusioncharts';
    import * as Charts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts';
    import * as PowerCharts from 'fusioncharts/fusioncharts.powercharts';
    import * as FintTheme from 'fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint';

    // Pass the fusioncharts library and chart modules
    FusionChartsModule.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, PowerCharts, FintTheme);

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        FusionChartsModule
      ]
    })
```

Also, you don't have to import js files in the index.html, instead, put them in the angular.json config.

```
    ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            ...
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.js",
              "src/assets/js/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts.js",
              "src/assets/js/fusioncharts/fusioncharts.powercharts.js",
              "src/assets/js/fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"
            ]
          },
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the app, include the ng-fusioncharts directive as a dependency. If you are looking for where to add the dependency, look for the call to angular.module in your code

```
angular.module("myApp", ["ng-fusioncharts"])
```

Add the fusioncharts directive In your HTML, define a element with fusioncharts directive where you want to add the chart.

```
<div ng-controller="MyController">
 <div fusioncharts
      width="600"
      height="400"
      type="column2d"
      dataSource="{{myDataSource}}" >
 </div>
</div>

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {

    //Define the `myDataSource` scope variable.  
    $scope.myDataSource = {
       chart: {
           caption: "Harry's SuperMart",
           subCaption: "Top 5 stores in last month by revenue",
           numberPrefix: "$",
           theme: "fint"
       },
       data:[{
           label: "Bakersfield Central",
           value: "880000"
       },
       {
           label: "Garden Groove harbour",
           value: "730000"
       },
       {
           label: "Los Angeles Topanga",
           value: "590000"
       },
       {
           label: "Compton-Rancho Dom",
           value: "520000"
       },
       {
           label: "Daly City Serramonte",
           value: "330000"
       }]
    };
    });
```

To know more about it please check - https://www.fusioncharts.com/blog/angular-fusioncharts/

Here is the integration docs - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/getting-started/angular/angularjs/your-first-chart-using-angularjs